# Products of conditional probabilities for sequence modeling

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, machine-learning

In machine learning I often see expressions of the form

$$P(x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(x_i | x_{i-1}, x_{i-2}, ..., x_2, x_1)$$

(eg. [here, page 2](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/bengio03a/bengio03a.pdf)) when modeling sequences (where $P$ is a probability-valued function, ie. a function that maps "things" to probabilities). I don't understand what these expressions mean (anyone care to explain?), but it makes me wonder if the following is true:

$$
P(x_n|x_{n-1}) \cdot \ldots \cdot P(x_3 | x_2) \cdot P(x_2 | x_1) = P(x_n | x_{n-1}, \ldots, x_2, x_1)
$$

and why (not)? And, if not, under what conditions is it true?

Comment: It's [Bayes' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#For_continuous_random_variables) applied recursively. BTW, in the referenced source, the conditioning is on $(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1})$. Your version works for Markov processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first expression is just the recursive application of the **definition** of **conditional probability.**

Let $x,y,z$ be random variables (or events?).

By definition, the conditional probability (law? density? cumulative?) $p[x | y]$ (which people call "$x$ **given** $y$", but I think of as "**the probability of $x$ in the $y$-world**", or "**$x$ under the $y$-lens**") is:

$$p[x|y] := {p[x \cap y] \over p[y]}.$$

Now:

$$p[x \cap y] == p[x|y] * p[y]$$
$$p[x \cap y] == p[y|x] * p[x]$$

Therefore:

$$p[x \cap y \cap z] == p[x \cap (y \cap z)] == p[x|y \cap z] * p[y \cap z] == p[x|y \cap z] * p[y|z] * p[z]$$
$$p[x \cap y \cap z] == p[y \cap (z \cap x)] == p[y|z \cap x] * p[z \cap x] == p[y|z \cap x] * p[z|x] * p[x]$$
$$p[x \cap y \cap z] == p[z \cap (x \cap y)] == p[z|x \cap y] * p[x \cap y] == p[z|x \cap y] * p[x|y] * p[y].$$